# ¿Cómo capturar el mensaje del input de una notificación push?, usando en el servidor el paquete de web-push de npm

Tags: nodejs, angular, push-notification, service-workers

Tengo todo la gran parte funcionando, al emitir la notificación llega al navegador, con su campo para escribir una respuesta.
Lo que sucede es que cuando le escribo un mensaje y le doy en el botón responder, en el evento de escucha de click o mensaje no se muestra el texto escrito en el input.

En el siguiente fragmento muestro el envío de la notificación desde el servidor está escrito en Nodejs:

```
 public async testNotificationPush(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    const { token }: any = req.body;
    try {
        //#region Validate params
        const validation = await ValidateParams(req.body, { requiredParameters: { token } });
        if (validation != true)
            return res.status(400).json(setResponse({ text: 'Los parámetros son inválidos', errors: validation, status: 700 }));
        //#endregion

        const payload: IPayloadNotificationPush = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Prueba',
                body: 'Jairo: Esto es una prueba',
                icon: 'assets/icons/icon-384x384.png',
                actions: [
                    { action: 'reply', title: 'Responder', type: 'text' }
                ],
                data: {
                    onActionClick: {
                        default: { operation: 'navigateLastFocusedOrOpen', url: '/#/home/' },
                        reply: {
                            operation: 'navigateLastFocusedOrOpen',
                            url: '/#/home/',
                        }
                    },
                },
                badge: 'assets/icons/icon-128x128.png'
            },
        };
        for (const item of token) {
            await notificationPush.SendWeb(0, payload, JSON.stringify(item));
        }
        TestAny.response = setResponse({ text: 'Envio exitoso', data: {} });
        TestAny.code = 200;

        return res.status(TestAny.code).json(TestAny.response);
    } catch (error: any) {
        return res.status(500).json(setResponse({
            text: 'Ha ocurrido un error inesperado', errors: error.message, status: 801
        }));
    }
}
```

En la siguiente parte se muestra la escucha de eventos correspondientes, escritos en Angular:

```
  this.swPush.notificationClicks.subscribe(data => {
  console.log("notificationClick", data.notification);
  console.log("action", data.action);
  console.log("message", data.notification.data.message);
  console.log("text", data.notification.data.text);

},);
this.swPush.messages.subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log("message", data);
  console.log("messages", data.notification.data.message);
})
```

La notificación cuando se emite se ve como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Vista de la notificación push]

A continuación les muestro la data de como se muestra en la consola cuando se le da click con un texto escrito:

**Datos mostrados en el console.log de message:**

```
{
"notification": {
    "title": "Prueba",
    "body": "Jairo: Esto es una prueba",
    "icon": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
    "actions": [
        {
            "action": "reply",
            "title": "Responder",
            "type": "text"
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "onActionClick": {
            "default": {
                "operation": "navigateLastFocusedOrOpen",
                "url": "/#/home/"
            },
            "reply": {
                "operation": "navigateLastFocusedOrOpen",
                "url": "/#/home/"
            }
        }
    },
    "badge": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png"
}
```

}

**Datos mostrados en el console.log de notificationClick:**

```
{
"actions": [
    {
        "action": "reply",
        "icon": "",
        "placeholder": null,
        "title": "Responder",
        "type": "text"
    }
],
"badge": "https://5821-2800-e2-a00-30b-34ea-7c65-642b-b17c.ngrok.io/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
"body": "Jairo: Esto es una prueba",
"data": {
    "onActionClick": {
        "default": {
            "operation": "navigateLastFocusedOrOpen",
            "url": "/#/home/"
        },
        "reply": {
            "operation": "navigateLastFocusedOrOpen",
            "url": "/#/home/"
        }
    }
},
"dir": "auto",
"icon": "https://5821-2800-e2-a00-30b-34ea-7c65-642b-b17c.ngrok.io/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
"image": "",
"lang": "",
"renotify": false,
"requireInteraction": false,
"silent": false,
"tag": "",
"timestamp": 1677073229843,
"title": "Prueba",
"vibrate": []
```

}

[image: Datos mostrados por consola]

**Si alguien ha podido resolver agradecería cualquier ayuda.**